# RSS feed xml output to JSON

Tags: java, jquery, xml, rss

I need to get JSON output of particular website's RSS feed XML. on click button, Output have to be displayed as JSON format in chrome response screen. Fetching all details from mention RSS feed URL.

Whether we can get this output using JS or JQuery?? I tried to use parseXML..but it doesnt work for me.

Please some one help me to give some tips.

Thanks

Comment: Why isn't it working? Please be (a lot) more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your prompt reply and very sorry for my late reply.

Using Java i need to grab this url content http://www.vogella.com/article.rss. will have 1 button on body of the page. On click, it should display RSS feed datas in JSON format as response. Nothing to display on body.

I m very new to Java environment. looking for samples in google.. cant able to understand complex codes.